# Stripe checkout one-time payments php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to set Stripe checkout for my website.

I created and verified my Stripe account, and now I need to set up the checkout page. I downloaded from Github the PHP stripe library (I have PHP 5.6.4, so compatibility is OK). Then I went in the Stripe documentation and found [this page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server).

I created a new page for the checkout, included the `init.php` from the Stripe library and pasted in the page the code found in the documentation page. When I open it, it gives back an empty page but I don't know why.

I don't know if this is the right procedure, but I searched online for like 2 hours finding nothing, and the documentation doesn't seem clear to me. Can someone help me?

I checked and the page doesn't generate errors. The code of the page is this:

```
<?php
require_once('assets/stripe/init.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_OW6K5e96gNXbAhEvPo15IB3C');

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'name' => 'T-shirt',
    'description' => 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
    'images' => ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
    'amount' => 500,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
]);
?>
```

This is what I copied in the page, still don't know if there's something to change or some other things to add.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs? 
Can you send post your code?

Comment: What do you expect to be outputted?

Comment: something like this: 
https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/ppage_1FXGCnFKnpzPB0MXupKRrQsJ#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWm9CPHY2XUhhVm9fQzxOYWgwYjA8f2lcYScpJ3dgY2B3d2B3SndsYmxrJz8nbXFxdXY%2FKip2cXdsdWArZmpoJyknaWpmZGlgJz9rcGlpKSdobGF2Jz9%2BJ2JwbGEnPydgMDxnNmNgNig0Yz08KDEwNjQoPDY8YSg0NDcyNzEyPTIxPDInKSdocGxhJz8nPTdjNjExND0oYGNmYygxMTw0KDw8ZjcoZD03YWFnZDQ8M2Q8JykndmxhJz8nY2QzZzc0ZjcoM2c8YCgxPWY8KGdhYTcoMj1hNzJhZjI1ZjxgJ3gpJ2dgcWR2Jz9eWHgl

Comment: You appear to have implemented step 1 on that doc, but not step 2. Step 2 is important.

Comment: Do i need to implement it right under?

Comment: Yes, basically. Step 2 relies on the `$session->id` you generate in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
require_once 'shared.php';
$domain_url = $config['domain'];
$base_price = $config['base_price'];
$currency = $config['currency'];
$quantity = $body->quantity;
// Create new Checkout Session for the order
// Other optional params include:
// [billing_address_collection] - to display billing address details on the page
// [customer] - if you have an existing Stripe Customer ID
// [payment_intent_data] - lets capture the payment later
// [customer_email] - lets you prefill the email input in the form
// For full details see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
// ?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} means the redirect will have the session ID set as a query param
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => $domain_url . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => $domain_url . '/canceled.html',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [[
      'name' => 'Pasha photo',
      'images' => ["https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=4"],
      'quantity' => $quantity,
      'amount' => $base_price,
      'currency' => $currency
    ]]
  ]);

echo json_encode(['sessionId' => $checkout_session['id']]);
```

for more details and demo code : 
https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/tree/master/client-and-server/server/php/public